# The center of the Spin group written in the matrix of Spinor representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, spin-geometry

My question concerns how to write the center of the Spin group written in the matrix of Spinor representation.

(1). For example, for $Spin(3)=SU(2)$, we have that the center

> $$Z(Spin(3))=Z(SU(2))=\mathbb{Z}/2.$$

If we express the $Spin(3)=SU(2)$ in terms of the spinor representation (the 2-dimensional representation), we write the $Spin(3)=SU(2)$ as a rank-2 matrix.

**Question**: Now how can we write the center of the $Spin(3)$ group written in the matrix of Spinor representation as a rank-2 matrix:

> Ans: $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> -1& 0
> \\
> 0& -1
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$

(2). Now, my question, for $Spin(6)=SU(4)$, we have that the center

> $$Z(Spin(6))=\mathbb{Z}/4.$$

If we express the $Spin(6)$ in terms of the spinor representation (the $2^3=8$-dimensional representation), we write the $Spin(6)$ as a rank-8 matrix.

**Question**: How can we write the center of the $Spin(6)$ group written in the matrix of Spinor representation as a rank-8 matrix?

(3). Now, my question, for $Spin(10)$, we have that the center

> $$Z(Spin(10))=\mathbb{Z}/4.$$

If we express the $Spin(10)$ in terms of the spinor representation (the $2^5=32$-dimensional representation), we write the $Spin(10)$ as a rank-32 matrix.

**Question**: How can we write the center of the $Spin(10)$ group written in the matrix of Spinor representation as a rank-32 matrix or a rank-16 matrix?

p.s. Helpful Refs on [Spinor representation](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf).

Comment: Can one identify the elements of the Spin groups with elements of the Clifford Algebras having every element of the Spin groups act by conjugation and then use a matrix representation of the Clifford Algebras?

Comment: @16278263789, thanks, if you have an explicit matrix, it will be great and counts as an answer!!! +1

Comment: Here is a useful ref: http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/clifford.pdf

Comment: I'll try to fully write it out today! Thanks for the reference!